# Ruby - Add values of array of hash by respective keys

Tags: ruby

I have a array of hashes

`arr = [{a: 1, b: 2, c:3}, {a:2, b:10, c:2}, {a:9, b:2, c:8}]`

I need to add values of the by their respective keys. The output should be like

`{a: 12, b: 14, c: 13}` or `[{a: 12, b: 14, c: 13}]`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try anything before asking?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "How can I achieve this?" – You can achieve this by writing a program which does what you want. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr.inject do |result_so_far, hash|
  result_so_far.merge(hash) do |_, total_so_far, value_from_hash|
    total_so_far + value_from_hash
  end
end
```

[`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) in an array takes a value to start with and combines it with a previous result.
[`merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) on a hash combines 2 hashes, using the block to define handling of duplicate keys, in this case by adding to the total so far for the key.

Another way could be we iterate each array element and each hash and add values to a new hash

```
new_hash =  Hash.new(0)
arr.each { |hash| hash.each { |key, value| new_hash[key] += value } }
puts new_hash
```

Comment: use of `merge` here is great. I've just edited the answer to add a bit more detail, hope that's alright.

Comment: This is a good answer. Though I would have used more semantic block variable names.

Comment: @SagarPandya yep, I was thinking exactly the same about the variable names. Will get them in.

Comment: For #2, perhaps write `arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |hash, new_hash| ....`.